# Count and group data in a CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, rdd

I have csv file as Leave.csv

```
EmpId,LeaveType,Designation
1,Sick,SE
1,Casual,SE
2,Sick,SE
3,Privilege,M
1,Casual,SE
2,Privilege,SE
```

Now I want the data  as

```
EmpID-1 
Sick : 2
Casual : 2
Privilege : 0
```

Using spark in Java

I have done the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

JavaSparkContext context = SparkConnection.getContext();
JavaRDD<String> empRdd=context.textFile("Data\\Employee.csv");
JavaRDD<String> leaveRdd=context.textFile("Data\\Leave.csv");

PairFunction<String, String, String> leaveKey=new PairFunction<String, 
String,String>() {

    @Override
    public Tuple2<String,  String> call(String t) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2(t.split(",")[0],t.split(",")[1]);
    }
};

   JavaPairRDD<String, String> leavepairs=leaveRdd.mapToPair(leaveKey)
                                                .reduceByKey(new 
    Function2<String, String, String>() {

    @Override
    public String call(String v1, String v2) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return v1+v2;
    }
});
int count=(int) leavepairs.count();
for (Tuple2<String, String> s: leavepairs.take(count)) {
    System.out.println("Emp Id : "+s._1 +"Leave type : "+s._2 );


    }

      }
```

and I am getting the below output :

```
 Emp Id : ?EmpIdLeave type : LeaveType
 Emp Id : 2Leave type : SickPrivilege
 Emp Id : 3Leave type : Privilege
 Emp Id : 1Leave type : SickCasualCasual
```

Please suggest what should i do for the desired o/p in the pattern :

```
 EmpID-1 
 Sick : 1
 Casual : 2
 Privilege : 0
```

Comment: ... That isn't JSON

Comment: Anyway. Why are you not using Spark CSV to read your file? Dataframes would be easier to use here... Can you explain in words what you tried to do in this code?

Comment: I am using csv file  only  . I wanted the result in json . But for the time being i can skip the json part . I just want to get the ouput printed .

Comment: So basically i had got a key value pair from leaveRdd where key is empId and value is Leave type . Then I have used reduceByKey to get the o/p.I am very new to Spark so I managed to do this much only . Also i dont want to use Spark  SQL

Comment: The output you want does not contain the words "Leave type", so why are you printing it?

Comment: Please see the schema of the data given above and compare the o/p i got , you will understand

Comment: And the keys you reduced by are not numbers. It's Sick , Casual, and Privileged

Comment: I am not getting you . Can you please help me in getting the o/p. Actually i just gave it a try reading the spark documentation

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand your code... What's the actual input? `(t.split(",")[0],t.split(",")[1])` doesn't work because there's no commas

Comment: This is my table EmpId LeaveType Designation
1 Sick SE
1 Casual SE
2 Sick SE
3 Privilege M
1 Casual SE
2 Privilege SE

Comment: Yes, again. There are no commas there...

Comment: This is a comma seperated csv file and hence i am splitting using ,

Comment: Did you get my problem statement ? If yes , Please provide me with your solution to do it

Comment: Please edit your question to show the correct input file. Since there are no commas in the data `t.split(",")[1]` should throw an exception with what you've shown

Comment: Dear , its a comma seperated csv file . xcl file converted to comma seperated csvfile . it dosent give an exception , I have already tried it . You can do one thinf , make an excel file , add data in it and save as comma seperated csv file and not as excel file

Comment: Yes, I know. But please show me where there are commas in the data in your question. `EmpId   LeaveType   Designation`, or `1       Sick             SE`... I'm not seeing it

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/680041/excel-saves-a-file-in-csv-but-it-keeps-the-columns-and-the-rows-as-they-were-in

Comment: EmpId,LeaveType,Designation
1,Sick,SE
1,Casual,SE
2,Sick,SE
3,Privilege,M
1,Casual,SE
2,Privilege,SE

Comment: If you are  using Spark 1, have you seen this library?
 https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering alternatives, potentially [CsvJdbc](https://github.com/jprante/jdbc-driver-csv) might be a way of doing this type query.

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] [table-alias.]column [[AS] alias], ...
  FROM table [[AS] table-alias]
  WHERE [NOT] condition [AND | OR condition] ...
  GROUP BY column ... [HAVING condition ...]
  ORDER BY column [ASC | DESC] ...
  LIMIT n [OFFSET n]
```

Comment: Thanks dear . I want to use spark only